# Find JMS queue size, using JMSTemplate

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I have access to a JMSTemplate on which I am adding and removing items from the queue. But there doesn't seem to be a direct API which tells me what is the number of remaining items in the queue.

How can I get the exact number of items that is available in the queue using the JMSTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no JMS API call to find the number of messages in a queue so an integration framework like Spring which uses the JMS API will also not have such a feature.

The closest you could get would be to use a [JMS QueueBrowser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) and iterate over the messages to count them.